# Pants exclude specific Python dependencies

Tags: python-2.7, pants

Currently, I am using pants to build and test our python2.7 packages. We started noticing the following error during run goal after pytests goal is completed. I tried adding constraints.txt file to exclude the dependencies its complaining about, but the error wouldn't stop. Is there a way to exclude these dependencies during the pants build step?

```
./pants test.pytest --coverage=auto tests/python/abcd/test/xyz 

[pytest]
[cache] 
No cached artifacts for 1 target.
Invalidated 1 target.
[run]
Failed to execute PEX file, missing compatible dependencies for:
 importlib-metadata
 zipp

No .coverage file was found! Skipping coverage reporting.
                   tests/python/abcd/test/xyz                                      .....   SUCCESS

FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try increasing the verbosity with:

```
PEX_VERBOSE=9 ./pants test.pytest --coverage=auto tests/python/abcd/test/xyz
```

and then respond here?

This error can be caused by a couple of things. Are you executing the PEX on the same operating system that the PEX was built on? Do you also include `platforms=[...]` in your `python_binary` function in your `BUILD` file?

Comment: here is the issue reported in PEX community with detailed stack trace - https://github.com/pantsbuild/pex/issues/871, Unfortunately PEX verbose exceeds start ackoverflow limit

Comment: Also the error is happening during pytest and not in python binary. I tried the approach explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979100/pants-includes-os-x-specific-python-wheels, but that doesnt help

Comment: Has your `.pants` file changed? Is this error happening locally or in CI on a different OS?

Comment: No changes to the pants ini file was made. We did not add any new dependencies. It started breaking all of a sudden. It is happening on both MacOS and Linux environments